# How can I find the most frequent largest element in list faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

The task is to find the most frequent largest element in given list

```
# for example we have list a
a = ['1', '3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '4', '3', '3', '1', '6', '6', '3','6', '6', '6']
a.sort(reverse=True)
print(max(a, key=a.count))
```

how can I make this simple script work faster?

Comment: you dont need to sort it, just read over the list and count. use a dict to keep count and then you go from what ever the time complexity of the sorting algorithm (probably O(n log n)) down to O(n)

Comment: The main problem is that if u have for example 2 elements with same counts, us must choose the largest one.
By the way I've also tried with dictionaries, but it's still slow

Comment: @Nullman 
o_d = {}
for i in a:
    o_d.update({i: a.count(i)})
print(max([k for k,v in o_d.items() if v == max(o_d.values())]))

Comment: you are running `a.count` n times, thats `n*n` which is worse!

Comment: What do you mean by "most frequent" largest element? Unless you are working with something that isn't a total order, the largest element is unique.

Comment: There's a difference between "the most frequent largest element" and "largest most frequent element".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you sort at all?

You got `n*log(n)` for sorting which does nothing for you here - you still need to go over complete `a` for the `max(...)` statement and for EACH ELEMENT go through the whole list again to `count()` its occurences - even if *all emements are the same*.

So for

```
["a","a","a","a","a"]
```

this uses 5 passes and counts the whole lists for each wich leads to `O(n²)` on top of `O(n*log(n))` for sorting - asymptomatically this is bound by `O(n²)`.

The basic approach for this kind is to use collections.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['1', '3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '4', '3', '3', '1',
     '6', '6', '3','6', '6', '6']
 
c = Counter(a) 

# "3" and "6" occure 5 times, "3" is first in source so it is 
# reported first - to get the max value of all those that occure
# max_times, see below
print(c.most_common(1))[0][0]
```

which up to a certain list-size may still be outperformed by list counting - as you remove the need to create a dictionary from your data to begin with - wich also costs time.

---

For slightly bigger list Counter wins hands down:

```
from collections import Counter

# larger sample - for short samples list iteration may outperform Counter
data = list('1332114331663666')

# 6 times your data + 1 times "6" so "6" occures the most
a1 = [*data, *data, *data, *data, *data, *data, "6"]
a2 = sorted(a1, reverse=True)
c = Counter(a1)

def yours():
    return max(a1, key=a1.count)

def yours_sorted():
    return max(a2, key=a2.count)

def counter():
    c = Counter(a1)
    mx = c.most_common(1)[0][1]  # get maximal count amount
    # get max value for same highest count
    return max(v for v,cnt in c.most_common() if cnt==mx) 

def counter_nc():        
    mx = c.most_common(1)[0][1] # get maximal count amount
    # get max value for same highest count
    return max(v for v,cnt in c.most_common() if cnt==mx) 

import timeit

print("Yours:   ", timeit.timeit(stmt=yours, setup=globals, number=10000))
print("Sorted:  ", timeit.timeit(stmt=yours, setup=globals, number=10000))
print("Counter: ", timeit.timeit(stmt=counter, setup=globals, number=10000))
print("NoCreat: ", timeit.timeit(stmt=counter_nc, setup=globals, number=10000))
```

gives you (roughly):

```
Yours:    0.558837399999902
Sorted:   0.557338600001458 # for 10k executions saves 2/1000s == noise
Counter:  0.170493399999031 # 3.1 times faster including counter creation
NoCreat:  0.117090099998677 # 5 times faster no counter creation
```

Even including the creation of the Counter inside the function its time outperforms the `O(n²)` approach.

Comment: so it gives me wrong answer, '3' instead of '6'

Comment: @Codi Your code has 5 * '3' and 5*'6' - Counter() is stable: `counter.most_common(1)` gives you the first one that has the max amount. "3" is earlier in your original list then "6" so it reports 3 _first_. Adjust it to `print(c.most_common())` to see all sorted ones.´

Comment: thank you for your answer, using counter is obviously faster, but how can I choose the largest element from several equally frequent elements
for example in this case I get list of tuples
[('3', 5), ('6', 5), ('1', 4), ('2', 1), ('4', 1)]

Comment: @codi see edited `counter()` example, getting the max amount from most_common(1)[0] - then getting the max value from all that have that amount.

Comment: thank you sir, very much it might be the shortest way, by the way I am solving a contest sample and their tricky testing system fails me on 35th test with 'Wrong Answer' message, absolutely can't imagine why

Comment: @Code sometimes you can get print outputs from such tests to indicate whats wrong - or inspect the input data - no sure whats wrong without that

Answer (score 1):

If you use pure python, `collections.Counter` may be the best choice.

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(a)
mode = counter.most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Of course, it is not difficult to realize it by yourself.

```
counter = {}
counter_get = counter.get
for elem in a:
    counter[elem] = counter_get(elem, 0) + 1
mode = max(counter, key=counter_get)   # or key=counter.__getitem__
```

For large list, using numpy's array may be faster.

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array(a, dtype=str)
vals, counts = np.unique(ar, return_counts=True)
mode = vals[counts.argmax()]
```

**EDIT**

I'm sorry I didn't notice the 'largest' requirement.

If you choose Counter:

```
max_count = max(counter.values())
largest_mode = max(val for val, count in counter.items() if count == max_count)

# One step in place, a little faster.
largest_mode = max(zip(counter.values(), counter))[1]
```

Or numpy:

```
largest_mode = vals[counts == counts.max()].max()
# even vals[counts == counts.max()][-1]
# because vals is sorted.
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner `Counter.most_common()` returns a list containing tuples, which needs to be indexed twice.

Answer (score 0):

A from scratch solution would be something likes this:

```py
elem_dict = dict()

max_key_el = [0,0]
for el in a:
  if el not in elem_dict:
    elem_dict[el] = 1
  else:
    elem_dict[el] += 1

  if elem_dict[el] >= max_key_el[1]:
     if int(el) > int(max_key_el[0]):
        max_key_el[0] = el
        max_key_el[1] = elem_dict[el] 

print(max_key_el[0])
```

I use a dictionary **elem_dict** to store the counters.
I store in **max_key_el** the max [key, value]. In the first if statement I sum the occurrences of the element and in the second if statement I update the max element, while in the last if I compare also the keys.

Using a list with **20000 elements** I obtain:

- For your solution 3.08 s,
- For this solution 16 ms!